# Some jquery code is not working while others are working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to bind a function to a click event. Everything working fine, but some lines of the function are not executing while other lines  working exactly as I want.

```
$("#search").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#search").prop("disabled", true); //not working
    $('#search-help').show(); //not working
    $('#search-help').text("Please wait while we are processing your request");//not working
    update_access_from_refresh(); //working fine
    ...
    do_search_ajax();
    // this function works just fine.
    ...
    $("#asin").removeClass("is-invalid"); //working
    $("#keywords").removeClass("is-invalid"); //working
    $("#search").prop("disabled", false); //I don't know its working
    $('#search-help').hide(); // I don't know its working
});
```

here I commented on the lines of code that are not working.

The lines of code that is not working, If I run this from chrome console it is just working fine. But from the function, it is not working.

Here is the relevant HTML code. I think it is not an issue with HTML. Cause when I run the code from the console, It works fine. But not working from the function.

```
<form class="search-form">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary mb-2">Search</button>
                </div>
                   ...
                <div class="mr-auto ml-auto">
                    <span  class="text-info" id="search-help" style="display: none;"></span> 
                </div>
              ...
          </form>
```

Some of the code is snipped from the html.

I viewed the page source, The code is up to date as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share relevant html code in your question so that we all can help you better

Comment: by looking at your code, you are disabling `#search` on first line and at the end you are enabling it and same is the case with `#search-help` as you are showing it first and then hiding it. What is `update_access_from_refresh()` function which is not working for you, share that code too

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar This line is working fine bro. I have commented with every line.

Comment: `var x = 1; x = 2;` My code doesn't work, why isn't x==1?  This is what you have.

Comment: Comment all of your code inside the method, then enable just one line of code and see if that works, when it does, try with the next.  You'll quickly find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the actions after you called ajax

```js
function do_search_ajax () {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
}
$("#search").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#search").attr("disabled", true); // working
  $('#search-help').show(); //not working
  $('#search-help').text("Please wait while we are processing your request"); //not working

  do_search_ajax().then(json => {
      console.log(json)
      $("#asin").removeClass("is-invalid"); //working
      $("#keywords").removeClass("is-invalid"); //working
      $("#search").prop("disabled", false); //I don't know its working
      $('#search-help').hide(); // I don't know its working
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <button id="search" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary mb-2">Search</button>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="mr-auto ml-auto">
      <span class="text-info" id="search-help" style="display: none;"></span>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Ah! Great :) I thats genius. What I think what javascript does, "calls javascript function asynchronously" and then also execute all the code. If I enclose that in the callback function then it will be executed when the function finishes its work. Thats what I was wanted. Thanks again